# Rational function and polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, rational-functions

Let $R(t_1, \cdots, t_n)\in \mathbb{R}(t_1, \cdots, t_n)$ be a rational function in $n$ variables. Suppose $R_i:=R(1, 1, \cdots, 1, t_i, 1, 1, \cdots, 1)$ is a polynomial in $t_i$ for $1\leq i\leq n$. Is it true that $R(t_1, \cdots, t_n)$ is a polynomial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$R(x, y) = \frac{xy + 1}{x + y}$